# Is there any way to DELETE all unused dart files in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I do have a flutter app.

Sometimes I share only specific parts of my code with other people, example: leave only one screen.

I want to automate the deletion of all the .dart files that are not imported, used or compiled anywhere. That way I cannot leak more code than necessary when I want to share only a specific thing

Example of the ideal workflow would be to run a command `cleanUnused` and all those files are deleted.

Is something like this possible and if yes how ?

I think it should be as there are linting tools already that notify you that some files is used no where but I guess it is complicated to figure out the dependency graph between them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter/Dart find unused files or widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64647404/flutter-dart-find-unused-files-or-widgets)

Comment: @Ivo thanks for the redirect. Unfortunately no because as op mentioned there "This package has been discontinued and is no longer maintained. Instead, the company moved to providing a paid service. It would be nice to find an alternate solution. – 
" I cannot use it to build something else on top

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a custom script or tool that can analyze your Flutter project's Dart files.

Comment: I've often pondered what a scriptable interface to the analyzer might look like, to write simple tools like "look for classes that are missing toString" or "look for unused classes" and other things.  The custom_lint package might provide the right API.